# I. i. d distributions as best car offers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading my probability text book and got stuck on what seemed to be a easy question: Let $X_0,X_1,\ldots,$ be i.i.d and imagine they are the offers you get for a car you are going to sell. Let $N=\inf\{ n \geq 1 \mid X_n > X_0 \}$. Then Symmetry implies $P(N>n)\geq 1/(n+1)$ (When the distribution is continuous this probability is exactly $1/(n+1)$, but our distribution now is general and ties go to the first person who calls.)___copying from the book.

I don't see why $P(N>n)\geq 1/(n+1)$. To me it seems: 
$
  P(N \leq n)
= P(N=1)+P(N=2)+...+P(N=n)
=  1-(1/2)^n
$
since $P(N=n)=P(X_n>X_0,X_1<X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}<X_0)$. 
So $P(N>n)=(1/2)^n$.

I appreciate it if someone will point out my mistakes and show me how to derive
$P(N>n) \geq 1/(n+1)$

Comment: "P(N=n)=P(Xn>Xo,X1n)=(1/2)^n."This is not displayed properly, what I meaned should be P(N=n)=P(Xn>Xo,X1<Xo,...Xn-1<Xo)=(1/2)^n.

Comment: Actually you do not explain why you think that P(Xn>Xo,X1<Xo,...Xn-1<Xo)=(1/2)^n.

Comment: @Did,after seeing the solution below, I realize my mistake now. Originally, I was thinking P(Xn>Xo,X1<Xo,...Xn-1<Xo)=P(Xn>Xo)P(X1<Xo)...P(Xn-1<Xo) and each term in the final product is 1/2. But the events (Xn>Xo) (X1<Xo)...need to be independent, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is the distribution function corresponding to the $X_i$'s then
\begin{align}
   P[N=n]
&= \mathbb{E}(P[N=n|X_0]) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(P[\{X_n > X_0\}\cap(\cap_{i=1}^{n-1}\{ X_i \leq X_0 \})|X_0]) \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left(P[\{X_n > X_0\} | X_0]\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}P[ X_i \leq X_0 |X_0]\right) \\
&= \mathbb{E}((1 - F(X_0))F(X_0)^{n-1}).
\end{align}
If the $X_i$'s are continuous r.v's then $F(X_0)$ has a uniform distribution (this is the probability integral transform). So the expected value can be computed as 
$$
  \int_0^1(u^{n-1} - u^n)du
= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}
= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.
$$

Comment: If the distribution is continuous.

Comment: @Did  Sorry, I had thought I read that in the question, but I see now that it was a conditional statement.

Comment: @Rookatu That's very clear. Thanks!

Comment: @SoWaiChung no problem, glad it was helpful!