# i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Looking at this question [I. i. d distributions as best car offers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727273/i-i-d-distributions-as-best-car-offers) I wonder about the following one:

> Can we find the distribution function of $X_N$ where,
>
> $$ N= \min \{ n \geq 1 \mid X_n > X_0 \} $$
>
> where the $X_i$ are independent identically distributed
>   random variables with say, density function $f$ and distribution
>   function $F$ ?

Any ideas will be appreciated!

**edit:** I have edit the question. I forgot to type the $X_N$.

In the answer in the link there is the probability $ P[N=n]$ expressed with respect to the expectation. How can we derive a formula with involving the expectation and depends only on $f$ and $F$ ?

P.S. I sorry if I write something silly, I have just start studying these things.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be one of the rare cases I know where the CDF is the most convenient approach... For every $n\geqslant0$, let $M_n=\max_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$, then, for every $x$,
$$
[X_N\leqslant x]=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}[x\geqslant X_n\gt X_0\geqslant M_{n-1}]=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}[x\geqslant M_n,A_n],
$$
where
$$
A_n=[X_n\gt X_0\geqslant M_{n-1}].
$$
The event $A_n$ is concerned with the ordering of the random variables $(X_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ and $M_n$ is their maximum hence $M_n$ and $A_n$ are independent. And $A_n$ is realized when the two largest values in an i.i.d. sample of size $n+1$ are obtained at times $n$ and $0$, hence, assuming from now on that the CDF $F$ is continuous,
$$
P(A_n)=\frac1{n(n+1)}.
$$
Thus,
$$
P(X_N\leqslant x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(M_n\leqslant x)P(A_n)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{F(x)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}.
$$
Differentiating both sides yields the PDF $g$ of $X_N$ as
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}f(x)\frac{F(x)^{n}}{n}=-f(x)\log(1-F(x)).
$$
Finally, the CDF $G$ of $X_N$ is such that
$$
G(x)=F(x)+(1-F(x))\log(1-F(x)).
$$

Comment: Dear Did thank you very much for your reply! I have just one question: Where exactly do you use that the CDF F is continuous to obtain the $P(A_n)$ ?

Comment: To ensure that there are no tie.

Comment: And why can we assume w.l.o.g that $F$ is continuous and not just right-continuous, by the well-known property ?

Comment: We cannot a priori and if the CDF is not continuous the computations become messier. But the question assumes that the PDF exists, right? And this suffices to ensure that the CDF is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Everything is clear now!

Comment: You are welcome. Nice problem, by the way. Where did you find it?

Comment: Looking the question in the link, I thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is elegant or not, but what I'd try is as follows: first,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{N=1\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_1 > X_0\} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}\{X_1 > x,\ X_0 \in dx\} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx  f(x)\left(1-F(x)\right)
$$ 
the last step by independence. Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{N=2\}  &= \mathbb{P}\{X_2 > X_0,\ X_1 \leq X_0\} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}\{X_0\in dx\}\mathbb{P}\{X_2 > x,\ X_1 \leq x\} \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}\{X_0\in dx\}\mathbb{P}\{X_2 > x\}\mathbb{P}\{ X_1 \leq x\} = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} dx f(x)(1-F(x))F(x)
\end{align*}
and similarly, more generally 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{N=k\}  &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx f(x)(1-F(x))F(x)^{k-1}.
\end{align*}
Does that look/sound correct?

Comment: I was wondering if in the question cited by the OP the question was already answered in that question

Comment: Oh... haven't followed the link, so no clue.

Comment: @ClementC.: Dear Clement C. first of all thank you for your reply. could you please explain what do you mean by $X_0 \in dx $ in the first line ?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}$ is the measure put in $dx$ by the probability measure associated by $X$. If $X\sim P$, you can also write $P(dx)$, and if $P$ is continuous wrt Lebesgue's measure (with density $f$), it becomes $f(x)dx$.